# Is JasperReports can be a good replacement for a CGI based web report framework

Tags: java, jasper-reports, reporting

We have a CGI based web report framework written in C/C++. The *CGI* client connects with proprietary code which in turn connects to database.

We are looking for a better Java based replacement for *CGI* due to performance, maintenance and probably security factors.

- Can *JasperReports* connect with the proprietary code? Or will *servlet* be enough to replace CGI client?
- Can be *JasperReports* run on Tomcat?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

Jasper works great in Tomcat.  JasperReports is not limited to using SQL as a data source - it would be pretty easy to write your own data provider that interacts with your proprietary code.

If the proprietary code is native, you'll have to figure out how to handle that part of it, though...

Answer (score 4):

It's been a while but I remember it being really, really easy to create your own datasource in JasperReports.

See JRDataSource under [API Docs](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

You (or anyone else with a similar question) can check out this [partial custom data source example](http://gilbertadjin.wordpress.com/2009/07/01/inserting-images-from-database-into-jasper-reports/) to get started. I've found Jasper Reports to be quite easy to set up a basic system and integrate with. The documentation is not quite complete, but the code is somewhat more understandable than BIRT. Data from Java beans, Hibernate, and POJOs is all usable...